# what is the error Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: css, reactjs

./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Module not found: You attempted to import ../fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

I am getting this  error. so in the App.css file i have @font-face, and i have font family poppinsregular and poppinssemibold.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinsregular';
    src: url('../fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinssemibold';
    src: url('../fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: where is your `fonts` folder located relative to `src`? If it's something like this `src > fonts` you need to change your path from `../fonts` to `./fonts` .. if its outside of the `src` folder, create a static folder somewhere in src and go from there eg: `src/assets/fonts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute path to the asset (*likely the public folder*). Looks like you have fonts in a standalone directory in the project root. If it's in the public folder it is bundled up and accessible.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinsregular';
    src: url('/fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinssemibold';
    src: url('/fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Or move (or check) that the `/fonts` directory is within the `/src` directory. Perhaps this *.css file is in the src root and `/fonts` is actually within `/src`, perhaps you meant `.` instead of `..` to mean the current directory then `fonts`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinsregular';
    src: url('./fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./fonts/poppins-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinssemibold';
    src: url('./fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./fonts/poppins-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```